# CCActionMoveBy doesnot working properly when the action called for many of the sprite in cocos2d

Tags: sprites, cocos2d-iphone, objective-c

I have an issue with `CCActionMoveBy` when I call the movement action for many of my sprites. I need to move to a certain position and then remove it from the scene.

My problem is If the call the action for one or two positions its working fine, but when I call this action for more than 5 positions, the sprite doesn't move to the correct position.

My Frames are between 15 and 20, and I am not sure If there is a correlation.

Here is my Code :

```
[_sprite1[1][1] runAction:[CCActionSequence actions:[self moveWithPosition:ccp(60,-10)], remove, nil]];
[_sprite2[1][1] runAction:[CCActionSequence actions:[self moveWithPosition:ccp(10, 80)], remove, nil]];
[_sprite3[1][1] runAction:[CCActionSequence actions:[self moveWithPosition:ccp(-10,- 80)], remove, nil]];
[_sprite4[1][1] runAction:[CCActionSequence actions:[self moveWithPosition:ccp(-60, 10)], remove, nil]];
```

the above code is calling action for sprite with its position[1][1] like that i am calling many of the position at a same time for sprite.

Here the method for CCActionMoveBy

```
-(CCActionMoveBy *) moveWithPosition:(CGPoint) distance{

    return [CCActionMoveBy actionWithDuration:MoveTime position:ccp(distance.x, distance.y)];
}
```

MoveTime = 0.25f;

if you need more information i will update please help on this issue..